# "Map container not found"error with dc.js charts

Tags: leaflet, d3

I am trying to show marker cluster on dc.js charts ,I have around 30,346 data in json file i an stuck with one error map container not found

```
<script> var map = L.map( 'map', {
    center: [20.5937,78.9629],
    minZoom: 2,
    zoom: 3 });

        var Markers = new L.FeatureGroup();

        L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {             attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',          subdomains: ['a','b','c']       }).addTo( map );


        d3.json("file/data1.json", function(error, data) {  

Blockquote

            var beerData = data.items;
             drawMarkerSelect(beerData);        //var fullDateFormat = d3.time.format('%a, %d %b %Y %X %Z');        //var yearFormat = d3.time.format('%Y');        //normalize/parse data so dc can coorrectly sort and bin them       beerData.forEach(function(d) {
                d.YEAR_OBS = d.YEAR_OBS.match(/\d+/)[0];        d.DISTRICT = d.DISTRICT.match(/\w+/);


                        d.MONSOON = +d.MONSOON;             d.PREMONSOON = +d.PREMONSOON;           d.POSTMONSOO=+d.POSTMONSOO;             d.POSTMONS_1=+d.POSTMONS_1;

                    });

        //set crossfilter       var ndx = crossfilter(beerData);

        //create dimensions (x-axis values)         var yearDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.YEAR_OBS;}),
          dist = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.DISTRICT;}),       //dc.pluck:  short hand for same kind of anonymous function we used for yearDim

                ratingDim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck('MONSOON')),
                    ratingDim1 = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck('PREMONSOON')),
                    ratingDim2 = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck('POSTMONSOO')),
                    ratingDim3 = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck('POSTMONS_1')),
                //commRatingDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.beer.rating_score;}),
                //abvDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.PREMONSOON;}),
                //ibuDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.beer.beer_ibu;}),
                allDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d;});

        //creating groups (y-axis values)       var all = ndx.groupAll();       var countPerYear = yearDim.group().reduceCount(),       countPerDist = dist.group().reduceCount(),

                countPerRating = ratingDim.group().reduceCount()
                countPerRating1 = ratingDim1.group().reduceCount()
                countPerRating2 = ratingDim2.group().reduceCount()
                countPerRating3= ratingDim3.group().reduceCount();
                //countPerCommRating = commRatingDim.group().reduceCount();
                //countPerABV = abvDim.group().reduceCount();
                //countPerIBU = ibuDim.group().reduceCount();

        //creating charts       var yearChart = dc.pieChart('#chart-ring-year'),         monthChart   = dc.pieChart('#chart-ring-month'),

                ratingCountChart = dc.barChart('#chart-rating-count'),
                ratingCountChart1 = dc.barChart('#chart-community-rating-count'),
                ratingCountChart2 = dc.barChart('#chart-abv-count'),
                ratingCountChart3 = dc.barChart('#chart-ibu-count'),
                //commRatingCountChart = dc.barChart('#chart-community-rating-count'),
                //abvCountChart = dc.barChart('#chart-abv-count'),
                //ibuCountChart = dc.barChart('#chart-ibu-count'),
                dataCount = dc.dataCount('#data-count'),
                dataTable = dc.dataTable('#data-table');

        ////chart configuration

        //circle charts         yearChart           .width(150)             .height(150)            .dimension(yearDim)             .group(countPerYear)            .innerRadius(20);
                    monthChart          .width(150)             .height(150)            .dimension(dist)            .group(countPerDist)            .innerRadius(20);




        //bar charts        ratingCountChart            .width(300)             .height(180)            .dimension(ratingDim)           .group(countPerRating)          .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([-0.2, d3.max(beerData, function (d) { return d.MONSOON; }) + 0.2]))            .elasticY(true)             .centerBar(true)            .barPadding(5)          .xAxisLabel('MONSOON')          .yAxisLabel('Count')            .margins({top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 50});       ratingCountChart.xAxis().tickValues([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110]);

                ratingCountChart1           .width(300)             .height(180)            .dimension(ratingDim1)          .group(countPerRating1)             .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([-0.2, d3.max(beerData, function (d) { return d.PREMONSOON; }) + 0.2]))             .elasticY(true)             .centerBar(true)            .barPadding(5)          .xAxisLabel('PREMONSOON')           .yAxisLabel('Count')            .margins({top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 50});       ratingCountChart1.xAxis().tickValues([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110]);

                ratingCountChart2           .width(300)             .height(180)            .dimension(ratingDim2)          .group(countPerRating2)             .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([-0.2, d3.max(beerData, function (d) { return d.POSTMONSOO; }) + 0.2]))             .elasticY(true)             .centerBar(true)            .barPadding(5)          .xAxisLabel('POSTMONSOON')          .yAxisLabel('Count')            .margins({top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 50});       ratingCountChart1.xAxis().tickValues([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110]);
                ratingCountChart3           .width(300)             .height(180)            .dimension(ratingDim3)          .group(countPerRating3)             .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([-0.2, d3.max(beerData, function (d) { return d.POSTMONS_1; }) + 0.2]))             .elasticY(true)             .centerBar(true)            .barPadding(5)          .xAxisLabel('POSTMONSOON_1')            .yAxisLabel('Count')            .margins({top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 50});       ratingCountChart1.xAxis().tickValues([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110]);





        dataCount           .dimension(ndx)             .group(all);

        //data table        dataTable           .dimension(allDim)          .group(function (d) { return 'dc.js insists on putting a row here so I remove it using js'; })          .size(100)          .columns([
                function (d) { return d.OBJECTID; },
                function (d) { return d.YEAR_OBS; },
                function (d) { return d.MONSOON; },
                //function (d) { return d.beer.beer_style; },
                //function (d) { return d.rating_score; },
                //function (d) { return d.beer.rating_score; },
                function (d) { return d.PREMONSOON; },
                function (d) { return d.POSTMONSOO; },
                function (d) { return d.POSTMONS_1; },
                function (d) { return d.DISTRICT; },

                            ])  
                        d3.selectAll('a#all').on('click', function() {          dc.filterAll();             dc.renderAll();         });

        d3.selectAll('a#year').on('click', function() {             yearChart.filterAll();          dc.redrawAll();         });         d3.selectAll('a#month').on('click', function () {
    monthChart.filterAll();
    dc.redrawAll();   });



        dc.renderAll();

    });



        function drawMarkerSelect(beerData) { 
          var xf = crossfilter(beerData);
          var groupname = "marker-select";
          var facilities = xf.dimension(function(d) { return d.LAT,d.LON; });
          var facilitiesGroup = facilities.group().reduceCount();

          var marker = dc.leafletMarkerChart("#demo1.map",groupname)
              .dimension(facilities)
              .group(facilitiesGroup)
              .width(600)
              .height(400)            
              .fitOnRender(true)
              .fitOnRedraw(true)
              .popupOnHover(true)
              .cluster(true);

          var types = xf.dimension(function(d) { return d.DISTRICT; });
          var typesGroup = types.group().reduceCount();



      dc.renderAll(groupname);

          return {marker: marker};
        }



</script>
```

The problem arises when the browser tries to instantiate the leaflet map. I get this error message:

```
leaflet.js:6 Uncaught Error: Map container not found.
    at e._initContainer (leaflet.js:6)
    at e.initialize (leaflet.js:6)
    at new e (leaflet.js:6)
    at Object.o.map (leaflet.js:6)
    at Object._chart._doRender (base-leaflet-chart.js:12)
    at Object._chart.render (dc.js:1616)
    at Object.dc.renderAll (dc.js:251)
    at drawMarkerSelect (trial .html:399)
    at trial .html:141
    at Object.<anonymous> (d3.min.js:1)
﻿
```

​

Comment: Do you have a `<div id='map'></div>` somewhere in your HTML?

Comment: yes i have <div id='map'></div> in my map

Comment: And you have the `<div>` *before* the `<script>`, right?

Comment: yes <div> before <script>

Comment: I see that `L.map()` is being called from line 12 of `base-leaflet-chart.js`. What's the DOM ID of the map container that `dc.leaflet` is trying to use? Is the `<div id='map'>` declared before the DC.js code runs?

Comment: I am using like this and only map part is displaying but not the marker cluster  on map, and still there is error "map container not found"                                                                                        <div id="demo1">
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dc.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
 <script src="js/base-leaflet-chart.js"></script>